# How To Disable Particular Nodes (Including SubNodes) Of a Jtree

Tags: java, swing, nodes, jtree

How to disable nodes and sub nodes of `JTree`.
I have a tree structure Like. For `Catalog` users i want to disable all the `Orders` and `Accounts Nodes` ( And `Sub Nodes`). I search a lot but not get the solution. Lots of Thanks in advance.

```
  ERP
    Catalog
      CatalogF1
        CatalogF11
        CatalogF12
          CatalogF121 

    Orders
      OrdersF1
        OrdersF11
        OrdersF12
          OrdersF121

    Accounts
      AccountsF1
        AccountsF11
        AccountsF12
          AccountsF121
```

Answer (score 1):

This thread contains the code snippets that disables certain nodes in `JTree`.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/339551/GUI/java/disable-treenode-jtree

Comment: i was looking at this solution but could not understand the code

Comment: they are overriding DefaultTreeCellRenderer which renders each cell and doing stuff with it.

Comment: setExpandedState(javax.swing.tree.TreePath,boolean) has protected access in javax.swing.JTree gives exception

Comment: Can't be, you're overriding JTree and accessing `setExpandedState` from derived class.